# Query returning all instances of a contract based on it's code hash?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, storage, rpc

Looking to write a call that could return all the contract addresses of ink contracts matching a code hash of the contract via RPC.

What would be the best way to go about getting the list of contract instances matching the hash?

Thanks.

Comment: What types of contracts? I presume ink using the contracts pallet or evm & frontier, but please update your question to be more explicit?

Comment: You're correct, they are ink contracts.

Answer (score 2):

The pallet_contracts has the storage `ContractInfoOf` (see in the [code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L942)) which is a mapping of the contract info (that includes the [code hash](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/contracts/src/storage.rs#L55)) associated with a given account.

You can query all the elements stored here and get all the `account Ids` that matches your hash code.

An example of the query using PolkadotJS UI:

[image]